# SQL DECODE OR CASE OR IF

Tags: sql

I need to run the query according to the month

For Example

the sysdate is 01/04/2016 or after it has to select March 2016
else(before march 2016 or on march 2016) it has to select March 2015

Comment: Has to check according to Sysdate

Comment: Then execute the query. Or did you need debugging help with a current query? If so, post 1)your query, 2)what you expect it to do, 3)what it does not do that you expect, and 4)a sample data set

Comment: Not even a table structure?

Comment: select decode((to_char(sysdate,'MM')),((to_char(sysdate,'MM'))>03),sysdate,null) from dual

Comment: if the date pass current year march show sysdate else show '01/03/lastyear'

Comment: Tag dbms used. `sysdate` is product specific.

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't mention your DB or table structure, you can try something like this which might not work on some RDMS due to `date conversion`. Use appropriate one.

```
select 
  case when sysdate > to_date('01/04/2016','DD/MM/YYYY') 
   then 'March 2016' 
   else 'March 2015' 
end as MarchYear 
from yourTable
```